# Can I do a 1000% zoom with JavaScript vector art?

Tags: javascript, canvas, zooming, vector-graphics

I'm planning to commission a developer to help me create a simple mathematical art piece. I'm wondering if the following can be accomplished with JavaScript vector art, and if not, what approach you would recommend.

The image will start off with some intersecting lines forming a shape. This is essentially an image zoomed in 1000% or more, and the user can scroll to zoom out until the full image fits the width of the screen.

Naturally, an actual image of this size would be huge, so I'm thinking it would be better to draw it programmatically, which might also enable the line thickness to scale up a bit as you zoom out, so that they're not nearly invisible when zoomed all the way out. The image can not look pixellated when zoomed all the way in, but achieving this with some “trickery” like swapping out images is also ok.

Example:
[image: Zoomed in]
[image: Zoomed out]

Basically the reverse of zoom.it but at a significantly larger scale.
http://zoom.it/

Some libraries I've looked at are:
paper.js
fabric.js
leaflet.js
raphael.js

How can an extreme zoomout like this be accomplished?

Comment: Crucial research for this project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg

Comment: Ha ha, yeh I've seen that one ;) No need to worry though, as I've already been in touch with a freelancer and he made me a prototype of pretty much exactly what we're after in about 1 hour, so we're on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track.  I think what you want is very possible on the web using HTML5.  You are correct in that the easiest/best performing implementation of this would be using vector graphics.  You can use image tiles, however the preprocessing and bandwidth requirements for tiling get large very quickly.

Here are some of my thoughts from working with some of the libraries you listed:

- **Leaflet.js** - Leaflet supports both drawing SVG elements as well as image tiling (if you wanted to go that approach).  Leaflet is also "mobile first" in that it supports things such as pinch zooming and double tap to zoom out of the box.  Scroll zooming is also supported out of the box. Getting something up and going with Leaflet is simple.  As far as I know Leaflet is writing SVG to the DOM; which is something to keep in mind.
- **Raphael** - Raphael is capable of what you want, however you may need to implement zooming aspects yourself.  This is definitely possible to do and shouldn't be too difficult, but something to keep in mind.  Raphael will write SVG elements to the DOM; which can get a bit unruly if you have many many SVG elements.  However, you may be able to optimize this and create/destroy elements as you are zooming.
- **Paper and Fabric** - These both appear to render SVG to Canvas (different than writing SVG to the DOM).  These both look really powerful, and seem to have good APIs for zooming.  You would likely still need to hook up scroll/touch gestures to get zooming to work the way you want.  These both should perform very well as they are using lower level APIs which should bypass many issues you might have with doing this in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks! That's all the reassurement I needed really. We are having a prototype developed in Paper.js. Will hopefully have an update to share in a few days/weeks.